# MySQL REGEXP - Start or end anchors cause matching to fail

Tags: mysql, regex

in MySQL I have the following Regexp:

```
"^[0-9]+[a-z]?(\s?\-\s?[0-9]+[a-z]?)?$"
```

The string I test it on is `"1 - 3"` (Any number should work here), resulting in the following MySQL:

```
SELECT
"1 - 3" REGEXP "^[0-9]+[a-z]?(\s?\-\s?[0-9]+[a-z]?)?$"
```

Wich results in `false`. The thing is, it's not a mistake in my regexp-pattern, since the result is `true`if I either strip of the `^` at the start or the `$`at the end.

Is this a bug, if yes is there a workaround? Or did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Ps.: The purpose of the regex is to get the house number out of a street having the number at any position in the String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `\s` in Regexes.

Use `[[:space:]]` instead:

```
SELECT
"1 - 3" REGEXP "^[0-9]+[a-z]?([[:space:]]?\-[[:space:]]?[0-9]+[a-z]?)?$"
```

returns `1`.